# WP url: localhost / page / variable

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way for Wordpress to know that when I type:
localhost / foo / bar

FOO is an actual page ( rendered with my own script as a template ) and
BAR is given VAR that all the stuff displayed on FOO depends on
?

For now, when I type localhost/foo I get the page, everything works okay.
localhost/foo/bar produces a 404 error, though.

Obviously, no BAR page exists. How to turn BAR from being rendered as a page to be rendered as a variable?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to do some htaccess foo

Comment: @Farkie no, he can have the requested feature without doing anything on .htaccess

Comment: Maybe with a redirect on the 404 template. Best way is just to change the link to localhost/foo/?bar

Comment: @Farkie While this is an option, this is not what Greg Bialowas needs

Comment: @Greg Bialwas the `bar` will be a standard type of value ? I mean a string with x characters length? will be a mixture of string a numder ? are you going to have a form for the `bar` ( ie: /user-id-123-age-45 ) ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos BAR is going to be a name of the folder/dir where the images are being stored. My idea is to create a template page called FOO, which will trigger a display of all images inside BAR folder. 

I have this hierarchy: dir -> subfolder1, dir -> subfolder 2, dir - > subofler 32

where DIR is an actual link 

I have this hierarchy: 
Dir
 - subdir1

Comment: @GregBialowas so the `bar` can be `/folder-1/folder-2/folder-3/....` ? Is that a possible scenario ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos No, this will be very simple DIR -> IMAGES, no sub directories for DIR. I feel I am making a mess out of this:

DIR -> FOLDER1 -> images
 or DIR -> FOLDER 52 -> images or DIR -> folder12 -> images

Comment: @GregBialowas sorry for asking so many questions, but because I am confused with the `DIR -> IMAGES` can you give me an example of the URL as you like be finally ? Is that right : `http://www.my-domain.ext/images-page/folder-name/` ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos YES!, that's the idea: http://www.my-domain.ext/images-page/folder-name/. --- Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Because it is going more complex that what I though, and I don't have time now to deep look into the solution, can you tell me what you think will be the  final page slug? I already have the solution for a pre-defined page slug

Comment: @MerianosNikos thank you so much for bearing with me! 
The final link will be: url.com/katalog/bears or url.com/katalog/santa or url.com/katalog/fish or url.com/katalog/budda or url.com/katalog/animal --- where KATALOG alwasy remains, and, in my original idea, is a WP templated page (where I list all of the images of certain category, being this bear, santa, fish or budda, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

in your `functions.php` file you should add the following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(katalog)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&bar_variable_name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_tags');
function custom_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%bar_variable_name%', '([^/]+)' );
}
```

***Note***: In the above code I have name the `bar` variable `bar_variable_name`. If you like, you can replace the variable name with one that better meets your needs.

***Note #2***: In case you need to rename the page to something else, then replace the `katalog` with the slug of the new page.

After you have done with it, you should go in your WordPress dashboard, in the "Settings / Permalinks" and just save the current settings you use. This way you are going to flush the ReWrite rules of the WordPress.

Then in your theme folder, either create a template page or in your `page.php` file and do the following test to check if you are in a page comming with `bar` and what is the `bar` value:

```
global $wp_query;

if (
    isset( $wp_query->query ) &&
    key_exists( 'bar_variable_name', $wp_query->query ) &&
    ! empty( $wp_query->query['bar_variable_name'] )
) {
    $image_path = $wp_query->query['bar_variable_name'];

    echo "This is my folder name : " . $image_path;
    die();
}
```

***Note***: In case you replaced the `bar_variable_name` in the previews code block, then update this code by replacing also the `bar_variable_name` here too.

If all are going well, when you will visit the `katalog` page with an extra segment in the URL you should see the segment string in your page.

ie: if you visit the page /katalog/beers/ the output it should be : `This is my folder name : beers`.

If that does what you need, then you can use the `$image_path` as variable inside your custom page to display what ever you like.

Comment: Also in case you feel I have solve your issue up vote my answer and check it as the right answer :) ;) :) Thanks ...

Comment: Added function.php part, created a template.
Template works, echoing a default PHP command ( 'hello' ), but when I add /bar to it, then 404 error is produced. Could this be because I've been placing all of this into a child theme? I mean child->functions.php, child->template.php etc?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Did you flush your re write rules of WordPress ? You can also try this plugin to inspect your re-write rules and flush them : https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/rewrite-rules-inspector

Comment: Notice, that re-write rules inspector has also a field on top of the re-writes you can use it to see what rule it is matching a specific URL. In this field you should add the path. In example if you have the URL : `http://www.my-site.ext/katalog/beers` in this field, you should add the `/katalog/beers` and press filter to see what rewrite rule maching your URL.

Comment: Finally I'd found some time to finish what I had started: went through your code again, finally added that plugin you mentioned. Suddenly, after flush, everything started to work as expected. Thank you very much for your help, much, much appreciated!

Ευχαριστώ πολύ

Comment: @GregBialowas xaxaxaxa !! You are very welcome :) Proszę ;)